# Web-based text editor (#2)

Tags: javascript

```
var appname = " - simple notepad",
    textarea = document.getElementById("textarea"),
    untitled = "untitled.txt" + appname,
    filename = "*.txt",
    isModified;

document.title = untitled;

textarea.onpaste = textarea.onkeypress = function() {
    isModified = true;
};

function confirmNav() { // Confirm navigation
    if (isModified) {
        var a = window.confirm("You have unsaved changes that will be lost.");
        if (a) {
            isModified = false;
        }
    }
}

function New() { // New
    confirmNav();
    if (!isModified) {
        textarea.value = "";
        document.title = untitled;
    }
    textarea.focus();
}

function Open() { // Open
    confirmNav();
    if (!isModified) {
        document.getElementById("selected_file").click();
    }
}

function loadFileAsText() { // load file as text
    var selected_file = document.getElementById("selected_file").files[0];
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onloadend = function(e) {
        if (e.target.readyState === FileReader.DONE) {
            filename = selected_file.name;
            document.title = filename + appname;
            textarea.value = e.target.result;
            textarea.focus();
        }
    };
    fileReader.readAsText(selected_file);
}

function rename() { // Rename
    filename = window.prompt("Name this note:", filename);
    if (filename) {
        filename = (filename.lastIndexOf(".txt") === -1) ? filename + ".txt" : filename;
        document.title = filename + appname;
    }
}

function Save() { // Save
    rename();
    if (filename) {
        var blob = new Blob([textarea.value], {
            type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"
        });
        window.saveAs(blob, filename);
        isModified = false;
    }
    textarea.focus();
}

function Print() { // Print
    var prnt_helper = document.getElementById("prnt_helper");
    prnt_helper.innerHTML = textarea.value;
    window.print();
    prnt_helper.innerHTML = "";
    textarea.focus();
}

function Help() { // Help
    var help = document.getElementById("help_content"),
        overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");

    function closeHelpAndOverlay() {
        help.setAttribute("aria-hidden", "true");
        overlay.setAttribute("aria-hidden", "true");
        textarea.focus();
    }

    if (help["aria-hidden"] === "true") {
        closeHelpAndOverlay();
    } else {
        help.setAttribute("aria-hidden", "false");
        overlay.setAttribute("aria-hidden", "false");
        textarea.blur();
        document.getElementById("overlay").onclick = function() {
            closeHelpAndOverlay();
        };
        // document.onkeydown = function(e) { // esc to close help
        //     if (e.keyCode === 27 || e.which === 27) {
        //         closeHelpAndOverlay();
        //     }
        // };
    }
}

// Confirm close
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    if (isModified) {
        return "You have unsaved changes that will be lost.";
    }
};

// Keyboard shortcuts
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    var key = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (e.ctrlKey) {
        if (e.altKey) {
            if (key === 78) {
                // Ctrl+Alt+N
                New();
            }
        }
        if (key === 79) {
            // Ctrl+O
            e.preventDefault();
            Open();
        }
        if (key === 83) {
            // Ctrl+S
            e.preventDefault();
            Save();
        }
        if (key === 80) {
            // Ctrl+P
            e.preventDefault();
            Print();
        }
        if (key === 191) {
            // Ctrl+/
            e.preventDefault();
            Help();
        }
    }
    if (e.keyCode === 9 || e.which === 9) { // tab
        e.preventDefault();
        var s = textarea.selectionStart;
        textarea.value = textarea.value.substring(0, textarea.selectionStart) + "\t" + textarea.value.substring(textarea.selectionEnd);
        textarea.selectionEnd = s + 1;
    }
};
```

Comment: Do you have a question, or any specific part of your code you want looked at? Or just anything and everything?

Comment: @Jeremy I'll assume "anything and everything"

Comment: yea you can say anything, the whole code, the way I coded this stuff. you may suggest me some simpler way if there are... and so on. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can optimize some queries.

```
var selected_file = document.getElementById("selected_file")
```

Unless your HTML changes considerably (replacing nodes periodically), every call to getElementById() will return the same node. You can access the node more efficiently if you cache the node in a local variable, and use the same local variable throughout your code, instead of looking it up multiple times.

Same with:

```
// Help
var help = document.getElementById("help_content"),
    overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
```

As long as all these elements exist when your code initializes, you can lookup and store them in variables once, instead of each time Help() (etc) is called. *In your code, the performance increase will be very minor, but it can add up in other situations.*

---

In your keydown block:

```
if (key === 79) {
...
if (key === 83) {
...

// function rename()
(filename.lastIndexOf(".txt") === -1)
```

You can shave a few bytes by using `==` instead of `===`. Since you're comparing primitives, not objects, `==` and `===` function equivalently.

Using `===` (instead of `==`) is a good practice when you're not sure, but it is unnecessary in the places you are using it.

---

It looks like you didn't update your last check in the keydown callback

```
if (e.keyCode === 9 || e.which === 9) { // tab
```

Can be rewritten as:

```
if (key == 9) { // tab
```

---

```
function confirmNav() { // Confirm navigation
  if (isModified) {
      var a = window.confirm("You have unsaved changes that will be lost.");
      if (a) {
          isModified = false;
      ...
```

---

While nothing is technically wrong here, I'd either like to see the `confirm` inlined into the `if()` or a more descriptive variable name. `a` is meaningless.

```
 if (window.confirm("You have unsaved changes that will be lost.")) {
 // or 
 var leavePage = window.confirm("You have unsaved changes that will be lost.");
    if (leavePage) {
```

---

Your code only has three long lines. The longest, at 136 chars:

```
var s = textarea.selectionStart
textarea.value = textarea.value.substring(0, textarea.selectionStart) + "\t" + textarea.value.substring(textarea.selectionEnd);
textarea.selectionEnd = s + 1;
```

I compacted it be using the local you already declared, and by adding a second. Now 97 chars:

```
var sStart = textarea.selectionStart,
    txt = textarea.value;
textarea.value = txt.substring(0, sStart) + "\t" + txt.substring(textarea.selectionEnd);
```

I don't think `s` was a bad variable name (`s` for selection or start is meaningful), but sStart is more clear.

---

You wrote some lovely, readable, and coherent JavaScript.

Here is everything:

```
var appname = " - simple notepad",
    textarea = document.getElementById("textarea"),
    help = document.getElementById("help_content"),
    overlay = document.getElementById("overlay"),
    selected_file = document.getElementById("selected_file"),
    prnt_helper = document.getElementById("prnt_helper"),
    untitled = "untitled.txt" + appname,
    filename = "*.txt",
    isModified;

document.title = untitled;

textarea.onpaste = textarea.onkeypress = function() {
    isModified = true;
};

function confirmNav() { // Confirm navigation
    if (isModified) {
        var leavePage = window.confirm("You have unsaved changes that will be lost.");
        if (leavePage) {
            isModified = false;
        }
    }
}

function New() { // New
    confirmNav();
    if (!isModified) {
        textarea.value = "";
        document.title = untitled;
    }
    textarea.focus();
}

function Open() { // Open
    confirmNav();
    if (!isModified) {
        selected_file.click();
    }
}

function loadFileAsText() { // load file as text
    var file = selected_file.files[0],
        fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onloadend = function(e) {
        if (e.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) {
            filename = file.name;
            document.title = filename + appname;
            textarea.value = e.target.result;
            textarea.focus();
        }
    };
    fileReader.readAsText(file);
}

function rename() { // Rename
    filename = window.prompt("Name this note:", filename);
    if (filename) {
        filename = (filename.lastIndexOf(".txt") == -1) ? filename + ".txt" : filename;
        document.title = filename + appname;
    }
}

function Save() { // Save
    rename();
    if (filename) {
        var blob = new Blob([textarea.value], {
            type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"
        });
        window.saveAs(blob, filename);
        isModified = false;
    }
    textarea.focus();
}

function Print() { // Print
    prnt_helper.innerHTML = textarea.value;
    window.print();
    prnt_helper.innerHTML = "";
    textarea.focus();
}

function Help() { // Help
    function closeHelpAndOverlay() {
        help.setAttribute("aria-hidden", "true");
        overlay.setAttribute("aria-hidden", "true");
        textarea.focus();
    }

    if (help["aria-hidden"] == "true") {
        closeHelpAndOverlay();
    } else {
        help.setAttribute("aria-hidden", "false");
        overlay.setAttribute("aria-hidden", "false");
        textarea.blur();
        overlay.onclick = function() {
            closeHelpAndOverlay();
        };
        // document.onkeydown = function(e) { // esc to close help
        //     if (e.keyCode == 27 || e.which == 27) {
        //         closeHelpAndOverlay();
        //     }
        // };
    }
}

// Confirm close
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    if (isModified) {
        return "You have unsaved changes that will be lost.";
    }
};

// Keyboard shortcuts
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    var key = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (e.ctrlKey) {
        if (e.altKey) {
            if (key == 78) {
                // Ctrl+Alt+N
                New();
            }
        }
        if (key == 79) {
            // Ctrl+O
            e.preventDefault();
            Open();
        }
        if (key == 83) {
            // Ctrl+S
            e.preventDefault();
            Save();
        }
        if (key == 80) {
            // Ctrl+P
            e.preventDefault();
            Print();
        }
        if (key == 191) {
            // Ctrl+/
            e.preventDefault();
            Help();
        }
    }
    if (key == 9) { // tab
        e.preventDefault();
        var sStart = textarea.selectionStart,
            txt = textarea.value;
        textarea.value = txt.substring(0, sStart) + "\t" + txt.substring(textarea.selectionEnd);
        textarea.selectionEnd = sStart + 1;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you very very much for such a detailed suggestions and advise...
I really appreciate it...

Comment: and I'd glad if you take a look at the complete app - https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/92126558/projects/ntpd/notepad.html

Comment: Nice, that's a very clean app. I'd recommend other ways to dismiss the Help dialog, esc, or an x in the corner. Now I see why you have the esc code commented. You can move the `closeHelpAndOverlay()` out of `Help()` to a top level function, then you can add  another `if` at the end of your main keydown, to handle esc and call `closeHelpAndOverlay()`.